# PHP Media Link shows gibberish

Tags: php, hyperlink, media

Never done a lot of work with media files but I have an odd problem. I have a media link

```
http://.../wb_media/3343/64999/0aa2233675f94a4fc8a3915175e218f3/1/4e5b9927-3a46-4c69-9929-cc7e2a52f616.png
```

Which is suppose to show an image in the browser yet it shows gibberish:
[image]

Not sure where I should start looking to solve this? I have verified this is indeed the correct link. I would even appreciate knowing what that gibberish is called so I can research the problem more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set header for the file type.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
print (file_get_contents("location/to/image.png");
?>
```

Or if you are not printing it through php script, then you must look into server configuration. How server handles mime-types.

Comment: Ah okay this link is provided via my API. Guess I will start by looking there thanks so much.